# How to call a input file from sd Card to csv reader?

Tags: java, android, csv, sd-card

I would like to call csv file from sd card,I have used CSVReader in my code.How to call the file,kindly help me with a snippet.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get SDCard path in which where you stored the .csv file and use following code to read data from CSV file

```
     File files=new File("/sdcard/files.csv");
     CsvReader producnts = new CsvReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(files)));
```

Where the file path should be path where you store your csv file.